# Email to sms using gsm modems

Tags: linux, sms-gateway

I'm looking for a email to SMS solution to run on Linux.
It's going to be a gateway for Smokeping to send alerts to asscoicated admins

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've done it but I recall it was fairly easy to do using [SMS Server Tools](http://smstools.meinemullemaus.de/) and a bit of scripting. It's even easier if you can skip the email part and have the software create a suitably formatted file in the SMS Tools outgoing directory.

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar set up for a few of our server locations. Most of them use a nokia mobile phone connected via serial and we use gnokii ( http://www.gnokii.org ) to pipe emails to it. The other solution we use is a cloud sms gateway and simply curl/wget a weblink to send the sms. There are a heap of services like this but we use clickatell ( http://www.clickatell.com )

Comment: Using an IP-to-SMS gateway like Clickatell as your primary and your own GSM modem as a secondary is a solid way to go.  If you need to be up as fast as possible, a gateway provider is usually the best route - Clickatell, for instance, offers many different APIs; so pick the easiest for you to script and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

Use the kannel sms gateway. www.kannel.org

Comment: It is usually not a good idea to rely on an external service for alerting in a monitoring system, as this will fail when your network connection goes down, which is something you **want** to know.

Comment: kannel can be configured to use a gsm modem as well, i recommended it as a configuration using a gsm modem not smpp

Answer (score 0):

Try [gammu](http://wammu.eu/gammu/). I'm using it to send SMS from my nagios using Vodafone with a UMTS stick. But almost any phone can be connected to gammu.

Answer (score 0):

I've yet to use cellular network solutions and have reasonable success with [cellular e-Mail gateways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways), however I do plan on looking into implementing one of these solutions.  They look to be really useful.

- [Foxbox](http://www.nagios.org/products/notification/foxbox) is a cellular gateway for the SMS network that Nagios supports
- [Walkthrough](http://www.chrisburgess.com.au/sms-gateway-how-to/) for building your own SMS gateway.

Comment: Foxbox is what I usually recommend.